# Final Cut Pro subtitle coordinates are not as expected when the project is vertical

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, subtitles, final-cut-pro

**For landscape video**

1. Create a project with 1920x1080 resolution
   [image: create project 1920x1080]
2. Add a 1920x1080 resolution image and add a subtitle by pressing `control+T`
   [image: Add image and subtitle]
3. Let's take a look when the subtitle on these four positions respectively:

left border center
[image: title on left border center]

right border center
[image: right border center]

top border center
[image: top border center]

bottom border center
[image: bottom border center]

For the four image above, we can draw a conclusion: the origin of coordinates is at the center of the video

For horizontal direction, we had 1920 pixels, half(960) for left and half(960) for right, the x coordinate of left border is -960 and is +960 for the right border

For now, everything looks right, everything acts as what I expected. **But this theory seems not work at vertical video(1080x1920) at all**.

---

**For vertical video**

For vertical video, it's in a similar way, it had 1080 pixels for the x axis, half for top side and half for the bottom side, the y coordinate of the top border is +540 and it's -540 for the bottom border.

1. Create a project with 1080x1920 resolution
   [image: create project 1080x1920]
2. Add a 1080x1920 resolution image and add a subtitle by pressing `control+T`
   [image: Add image and subtitle]
3. Let's take a look when the subtitle on these four positions respectively:

left border center(if it’s as we expected, the x coordinate should be close to -540, but why it's -294?)
[image: left border center]

If we set the x coordinate to -540, the subtitle is totally out of the video box
[image: subtitle out of the box]

right border center(if it’s as we expected, the x coordinate should be close to 540, but why it's 306?)
[image: subtitle on right border center]

If we set the x coordinate to 540, the subtitle is totally out of the video box
[image: top border center]

For vertical direction it's similar, it should be +960 and -960, but if we set it to +960 and -960, the subtitle is totally out of the video box
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Anyone who knows why the vertical video subtitle position not acts like it in landscape video?